# How to assign $_GET value to a variable using pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript, get

Hi guys can How to assign $_GET value to a variable using pure JavaScript I have HTML structure not php

Comment: Why not to use javascript to read get: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this

```
function getGETParameter(key) {
    var params = window.location.search.slice(1).split('&'),
        i = params.length;
    key += '=';
    while (i-- > 0) {
        if (params[i].lastIndexOf(key, 0) === 0)
            return params[i].slice(key.length);
    }
    return false;
}
```

You may also want to consider if you want to use [`decodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent) on these values as they may be URI encoded

---

If you want to also permit keys to be URI encoded then this method starts to have issues and you would have to create an *Object mapping*, which would look something like this

```
function getGETParameter(key) {
    var params = window.location.search.slice(1).split('&'),
        i = params.length,
        j,
        o = Object.create(null);
    for (i = 0; i < params.length; ++i) {
        j = params[i].indexOf('=');
        if (j === -1) // how do you want to treat found but no value?
            o[decodeURIComponent(params[i])] = null;
        else
            o[decodeURIComponent(params[i].slice(0, j))] = decodeURIComponent(params[i].slice(j + 1));
    }
    if (key in o) return o[key];
    return false; // how do you wan to treat not found?
}
```

You could also create and cache this *Object* in advance instead of generating it for each invocation

Answer (score -1):

combine the php code and javascript code !

```
var x=<?php echo $_GET['whatever'];?>;
```

so first the php code is being executed server-side and then it's result in html is assigned to a variable in javascript ...

Comment: This is not what Boyrock is asking

Comment: First of all, the question specifically asks for JavaScript only solution. Secondly this will result in a syntax error if the get parameter is anything other than a number.

Comment: in the title of question ... he wrote $_GET ... which is the notation of php !!! so i think he wanted !

Comment: So you're saying that when he wrote "using pure JavaScript" he meant "using PHP", and in the question when he wrote "not PHP" he meant "yes PHP"?

Comment: :D i mean using php and javascript ! see the other answer it is 10 lines of code and mine is just 1